# Android - Updating list view on spinner selection

Tags: android, listview, android-spinner

I am trying to update a list view, when I select on an item in spinner, the code works but no output is generated. I cannot figure out the bug.On every click on the item in spinner I want to view different list.

```
Spinner spinner;
String path[] = {"Laptops","DesktopPC","Tablets","Add-Ons","Gaming"};
String Laptops[] = {"Dell","Hp","Apple"};
ListView lstView;


lstView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String> (Category.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, path );
spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
spinner.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
            int arg2, long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ArrayAdapter<String> lstAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, Laptops);
        lstView.setAdapter(lstAdapter);
        //lstView.refreshDrawableState();

    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `OnItemSelectedListener` and use a  `ArrayList<String>`. Use the same for your adapter. Add items to arraylist and call `notifyDataSetChanged` on your adapter to refresh lsitview.

Also there is no need to initialize your adapter in the spinner selection listener.

Modify the below according to your requirement

```
 Spinner spinner;
        String path[] = {"Laptops","DesktopPC","Tablets","Add-Ons","Gaming"};
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        String Laptops[] = {"Dell","Hp","Apple"};
        ListView lstView;
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter,listadapter;
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
             super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
             setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                lstView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
                for(int i=0;i<Laptops.length;i++)
                {
                    list.add(Laptops[i]);
                }
                adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String> (this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,path);
                listadapter = new ArrayAdapter<String> (this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,list);
                lstView.setAdapter(listadapter);
                spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
                spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
                spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                            int arg2, long arg3) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        String s = spinner.getItemAtPosition(arg2).toString();
                        list.add(s);
                        listadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }
                });

            }
```

Comment: i m stuck in when one clicks any spinner item, list should be generated according to the spinner item.and every spinner item has different array/list. Your code is almost to the query but its showing list view on default, i want the lit view when any spinner item is clicked.

Comment: @user2113484 you need to make sure you provide the correct arraylist for the adapter and it will work. Show me the code where you have different list for each spinner

Comment: the method u told above to put entire array into the list,and add that list into the adapter..i did that with all of my arrays and make some lists. Now all i want to do is to put switch/case in the setOnItemSelectedListener and pass array names in the case like (case "Laptops":) or (case "Tablets") on clicks they show there own lists which i had add/set previously from there arrays.

Comment: @user2113484 you can use this `String s = (String) arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2);` Now compare string s using `.equals` like  `if(s.equals("Laptops"))` then do something

Answer (score 0):

Use notifying that data set has been changed instead of setting a new adapter.

```
// Inside Event callback
 path = Laptops; // This is how you change data set
 lstView.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Answer (score -1):

Use Spinner `onitemSelectedListener` instead of `onItemClickListener`

Try the following :

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
        // your code here


  ArrayAdapter<String> lstAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, Laptops);
                    lstView.setAdapter(lstAdapter);
                    lstView.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {
        // your code here
    }

});
```

Answer (score -1):

Add notifyDataSetChanged() to adapter like below....

```
spinner.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int arg2, long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                ArrayAdapter<String> lstAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, Laptops);
                lstView.setAdapter(lstAdapter);
                lstAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                //lstView.refreshDrawableState();

            }
        });
```

Comment: After setting a new adapter, notifying an adapter regarding the change in dataset doesn't make much sense. I think changing the data-set and notifying the adapter is sufficient in itself.